# Geolocation Override Not Working in Mobile Emulation with Chrome WebDriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, geolocation, mobileemulation

I am working on a project where I need to override the geolocation in both desktop and mobile emulations using Chrome WebDriver. The desktop emulation works as expected, but the mobile emulation couldn't really override the geolocation.

I've used the following code to initiate the Chrome driver:

```
chrome_options = Options()

mobile_emulation = {
    "deviceMetrics": { "width": 360, "height": 640, "pixelRatio": 3.0 },
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75 Mobile/14E5239e Safari/602.1" }
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)

params = {
        "latitude": 'some lat',
        "longitude": 'some lon',
        "accuracy": 100
    }

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = Service(executable_path='some path'), options = chrome_options)
    driver.execute_cdp_cmd(
        "Browser.grantPermissions",
        {
            "origin": "https://www.google.cl/",
            "permissions": ["geolocation"],
        },
    )
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Emulation.setGeolocationOverride", params)

driver.get('https://www.google.cl/')
```

The geolocation overriding works well in Desktop emulation. However, when I added the mobile emulation, the overriding did not work. That is, the mobile UI showed up, but when I scrolled down to check the location that Google identified, it was still my actual location.

Enrvionment: Linux, Chrome v114 (the newest Chrome version does not override geolocation in either desktop or mobile emulation)

Can anyone help me understand why the geolocation override is not working in mobile emulation and if it's ever possible to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a full https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase script for overriding geo-location.

`pip install seleniumbase`, then run with `pytest`.

For the mobile version, use `pytest --mobile` when running it.

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
BaseCase.main(__name__, __file__)


class TestGeolocation(BaseCase):
    def tearDown(self):
        self.save_teardown_screenshot()  # If test fails, or if "--screenshot"
        if self.is_chromium() and not self._multithreaded:
            # Reset Permissions and GeolocationOverride
            try:
                self.open("about:blank")
                self.execute_cdp_cmd("Emulation.setGeolocationOverride", {})
                self.execute_cdp_cmd("Browser.resetPermissions", {})
            except Exception:
                pass
        super().tearDown()

    def test_geolocation(self):
        self.execute_cdp_cmd(
            "Browser.grantPermissions",
            {
                "origin": "https://www.openstreetmap.org/",
                "permissions": ["geolocation"],
            },
        )
        self.execute_cdp_cmd(
            "Emulation.setGeolocationOverride",
            {
                "latitude": 48.87645,
                "longitude": 2.26340,
                "accuracy": 100,
            },
        )
        self.open("https://www.openstreetmap.org/")
        self.click("span.geolocate")
        self.assert_url_contains("48.87645/2.26340")
        self.save_screenshot_to_logs()
        self.sleep(2.5)
```

(Tested on Chrome 122 and working for both desktop and mobile formats.)